# Greater than and less than operators while searching through a SAM file

Tags: python, compare, mapping, bioinformatics

I seem to have run into an issue with some code I am working on.

Essentially I am trying to map a bunch of reads from a `SAM` file to their respective features I am getting from a `gff3` file.

I am running through each line in the `sam` file and pulling out the chromosome and start of the read, then comparing it to the beginning and end of the feature I am trying to map it to (in this case the `ORFs`).

This is all being done in a for loop with a number of `if` statements and `for` loops inside it.

The major problem I've been having is that for some reason my location is not working quite right. I'm looking at the line of the `sam` and checking line by line if the start site of the read is between the start and end of the feature and if it is doing some other stuff with it.

However, depending on what I do, the code either returns nothing as located in a feature, or it just randomly assigns things to a feature. It doesn't seem to be comparing them correctly.

I've tried a couple of different ways to compare the numbers even forcing them to `ints` in different locations and it gives me one of the two following (appears after code).

I was hoping that someone could perhaps help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code

`sam=open("qiseqalignCGD.sam", "r")`

for line in sam:

```
#print line

if "M0" in line:

    if "ChrA" in line:

        chrom=line.split()[2]#is it in chrom

        startlocation=line.split()[3] #where it is mapping to start

        if startlocation in ChromAcountingStorage: #look for duplicates
            count=0
        else:

            if chrom == "ChrA_C_glabrata_CBS138":  #for this one if it is in chrom A
                for i in featureschromA: #cycles through the features
                    countchromAfeaturekey+=1
                    insert=int(startlocation)
                    beginning=int(featureschromA[i][1])
                    end=int(featureschromA[i][0])
                    #print type(end)

                    if beginning <= insert and insert <= end: #checks if it is between that gene
                        #print "true" + "\t" + (featureschromA[i][0]) + "\t" + startlocation +"\t"+featureschromA[i][1]

                        if i in ChromAcountingUnique:
                            ChromAcountingUnique[i]+=1

                        else:
                            ChromAcountingUnique.update({i:01}) #counts how many times that key has appeared before then adds it to that keys value""

                        ChromAcountinglist.append(i)


                        ChromAcountingStorage.append(startlocation)
                        #print ChromAcountingStorage
                        count=0
                    else:
                         #print "false" + "\t" + featureschromA[i][0] + "\t" + startlocation +"\t"+featureschromA[i][1]
                         stall=0
                    countchromAfeaturekey=0  #resets the counter
```

example of results
middle number is the read that i am trying to map. Left number is start and right number is the end of the feature

false   67119   78299   70367

false   69627   78299   70612

false   70937   78299   71320

false   73333   78299   73623

false   74737   78299   76560

**false 77494   78299   81497**

false   80753   78299   85553

false   84864   78299   86594

false   86383   78299   87887

false   87716   78299   90471

false   90297   78299   92857

the one in bold should be true but is still returning false

other times if i try to convert them to ints elsewhere i get something like this

false   465618  77756   469181

false   469405  77756   472212

false   470353  77756   480145

true    1608    78299   2636

false   2671    78299   4809

false   11697   78299   13042

with a seemingly random one being called true

Anyone have any possible explanations?

Comment: According to your print line, index 0 is beginning and 1 is end. But you declared the opposite : beginning=int(featureschromA[i][1]) and end=int(featureschromA[i][0])

Comment: Ah, thank you for that. I guessed I must have missed it.